# How to use for Request and Response only one time in Java and Android

Tags: java, android, session

I'm developing a banking application in android. while calling webservices (API),I am sending the data as encrypted format and receiving the response as encrypted format.

While testing the application in Brup suite for mobile application.

Step1: User giving the mpin for login ,tester saving the request and response in notepad using burp suite they capturing.
Step2:After user loggedout ,now tester trying to login again using wrong password but it showing "wrong mpin" in that failure repsonse,tester putting the saved success response in burp suite.so its logged in succesfull

It not should not happen right. Captured request should not use again right. how to achieve this .

How to handle this issue? How to session timeout for request and response?

Please someone help me.

Comment: According to me, the question is not clear enough. Please edit it if possible.

Comment: i edited the question.pls help me

Comment: anyone can help me